# PHP - End execution of current file from within function

Tags: php, ajax, function, return

I want send error message to a form via AJAX as JSON data from PHP - numeric e.g. numeric code, text message and class (error, warning, success...)

I wonder If I can make function, which sends JSON header, echoes encoded data and ends up processing CURRENT FILE where it was executed.
I know I can do it in global code as return, but from within function?

e.g. data.php included into ajax.php, return ends processing of data.php and continues on ajax.php:

```
header(json...)
echo json_encode('enter your name', 'warning');
return;
```

And in func sth like:

```
function a($class, $message){
header(json...)
echo json_encode(array($class, $message));
//End processing ONLY file, where it's executed
}
```

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you're asking, but I think this is what you're looking for.

> Error Function

```
function error(array $data, $statusCode = 400) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    http_response_code($statusCode);
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
```

> Calling Function

```
error(
    array(
        'message' => 'Name was not filled in',
        'code' => 37
   )
);
```

> Output

```
Status Code: 400 Bad Data
Content-Type: application/json

{"message": "Name was not filled in", "code": 37}
```

> **Note, you need to make sure this error function is called before ANY output is sent to the browser otherwise it will not work as expected**

Comment: Ok. I see now I just need to json and exit. Thanks :)